# Use CSS to control text below images

Tags: html, css, image

So I have a simple page set up with three images on the left hand side. Beneath each image I want to add three lines: one plain text, one image with a link, and one javascript output.

Green text on first line:

```
<font color="green">User69</font>
```

Then on the next line a gif with a link:

```
<a href="http://google.comcom/?a=7337&c=6380&s1="><img src="online01.gif" alt="" border="0" style="float:center"></a><br>
```

On the third line the javascript output:

```
Location: 
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script> 
        <script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_region_name());</script></span> 
</script></br>
```

Those three bits after each image.

You can see at the moment that the text appears all over the place. The images are in the right place. But I can't control the other stuff except with line breaks and that's messy. There must be a better way.

Here's everything in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MzSZ4/1/

The problem should be pretty obvious!

Help very much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to use http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate your question.

Comment: Done. Link here: http://jsfiddle.net/MzSZ4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `float: left` in `.imgleft` this helps, at least in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you need three container divs. Each one containing the image, and the three bits of text you speak of. E.g.:

```
<div id=main-wrapper>
  <!--box 1-->
  <div class=box>
    <img class=img>
    <p class=toptext>TEXT</p>
    <img class=giflink>
    <p class=javascript-output>
  </div> <!--end of box div-->

  <!--box 2-->
  <div class=box>
    <img class=img>
    <p class=toptext>TEXT</p>
    <img class=giflink>
    <p class=javascript-output>
  </div> <!--end of box div-->

  <!--box 3-->
  <div class=box>
    <img class=img>
    <p class=toptext>TEXT</p>
    <img class=giflink>
    <p class=javascript-output>
  </div> <!--end of box div-->

</div> <!--end of main wrapper div-->
```

CSS:

```
float .box left
```